# Toggle between stylesheets with one button

Tags: jquery, css, button, stylesheet

I'd like to toggle between two stylesheets using a single button. The code I have currently is:

```
<link id="style1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link id="style2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleinvert.css" disabled="disabled" />

<script>
    function toggle() {
        var el1 = document.getElementById("style1"),
            el2 = document.getElementById("style2");
        if( el1.disabled == "disabled" ) {
            el1.disabled = undefined;
            el2.disabled = "disabled";
        } else {
            el1.disabled = "disabled";
            el2.disabled = undefined;
        }
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="toggle()">Invert</a>
```

However this causes the stylesheet to temporarily disappear between deactivating the first one and activating the new one.

Is there a better way to do this? Ideally I'd just to add a small snippet of style for the second stylesheet seen as I only need to change a few things like font color etc.

Comment: why not just add a class to the body tag and write overriding styles where needed?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that @KaiQing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic example of what I mean by adding a class to the body and writing override styles...

```
function toggle(){
    $('body').toggleClass('style2');
}

// css

p{
    color:green;
}

.style2 p{
    color:red;
}
```

the jquery toggle class docs: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "disabled" and undefined, use true and false:

```
function toggle() {
  var el1 = document.getElementById("style1"),
      el2 = document.getElementById("style2");

  if(el1.disabled) {
    el1.disabled = false;
    el2.disabled = true;
  } 
  else {
    el1.disabled = true;
    el2.disabled = false;
  }
}
```